# Applying fillna to a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I'm trying to apply the `fillna(0)` method on a list of dataframes, however it seems that a for loop isn't doing the trick. Essentially, I have 4 dataframes in a list as follows

```
Tox=[toxsnaus,toxvom,toxwt,toxanor]
```

now every dataframe in this list has some nan values that I want to fill with zeros, however when I try to fill them with a `for` loop

```
for tx in Tox: #fill all nans
    tx=tx.fillna(0)
```

This does not actually replace the values and instead just changes the values of tx in the loop iteration. How do I get it so that fillna(0) is actually applied to the dataframes instead of the iterator tx?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine if you fill nans in place, ie.:

```
for tx in Tox: # fill all nans
    tx.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Note that no assignment is needed. See the details in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to apply it back to the original dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,1,np.nan],})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,np.nan, 1],})

dfs = [df1, df2]

for i, tx in enumerate(dfs):
    dfs[i] = tx.fillna(0)

for tx in dfs:
    print(tx)

   col
0  1.0
1  1.0
2  0.0
   col
0  1.0
1  0.0
2  1.0
```